# Disable verification of certification SSL A7670SA

Tags: arduino-mega, http, networking

I have the code below and it doesn't work with my URL. I receive a

> 715(Handshake Failed)

This code below works normally, but with my API it doesn't work.

I'm using a A7670SA with Arduino Mega 2560.

My API is on Heroku and uses an Automated Certificate Management by Heroku, that uses the Let's Encrypt.

```cpp
String sendATCommand(String command, String expectedResponse = "", unsigned long timeout = 5000) {
  Serial1.println(command);
  Serial.println("Command send: " + command);

  unsigned long startTime = millis();

  String response = "";

  while (millis() - startTime < timeout) {
    if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
  }

  response.replace(command, "");

  Serial.println(response);

  delay(500);
  return response;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    ;

  delay(1000);

  Serial1.begin(115200);

  sendATCommand("AT", "OK");  

  sendATCommand("AT+CGREG?");
  sendATCommand("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"claro.com.br\"", "OK");

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPINIT");  // Iniciar ambiente HTTP

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://httpbin.org/\"");

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPACTION=0", "OK", 1000);

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPREAD?");

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPTERM", "OK");
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: what is your specific question?